# Panels with synchronized height

Tags: extjs

I have a panel with `layout='column'` and several (say, three) panels within it. All panels are displayed in one line.

Height of inner panels depends on their content and in general may vary. I'd like to set `autoHeight` to `true` in the inner panels for them to reflect content's height. But also I'd like the heights of all inner panels to be equal to highest panel.

What is the simplest way to implement this? I'm using ExtJs 2.2.

Regards,
Andrey

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the column layout, try using the HBoxLayout with autoHeight: true.

Comment: Unfortunately Ext 2.2 has no such layout class.